# Returning XML values in Async task throws exception with no message

Tags: android, xml

I am following the developer tutorial located at: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

For the most part it has gone well and I have it at about 90%, my problem is in my `XmlNetwork` class, i have the following function

```
    @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //return getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error);
        return "connection error";
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        //return getResources().getString(R.string.xml_error);
        String temp = e.getMessage();
        return "xml error";
    }
}
```

I have a break point at `loadXmlFromNetwork` and I can step thru the entire function, it's returning data, formatting it properly, and returning it out. as soon as it steps out of that function, and back into this one, it immediately jumps to `return "xml error";`. this is extremely confusing to me, since the data is formatted properly and returned as a string, it looks like everything is working. it also doesn't appear to be outputting any information to temp, so i can see what XmlPullParserException is being thrown, so i don't have a lot of debugging info to work with.

any ideas why it would jump from what looks like a correctly returned value in the function call, to an exception? or why the value of the exception wouldn't show?

i can also post both classes if necessary, let me know if you'd like to see the whole thing.

Thanks.

edit: stacktrace as requested

```
09-15 14:47:34.329  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
09-15 14:47:34.329  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
09-15 14:47:34.399  15698-15708/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/art﹕ Debugger is active
09-15 14:47:34.549  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
09-15 14:47:34.549  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
09-15 14:47:34.749  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
09-15 14:47:34.949  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
09-15 14:47:35.149  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
09-15 14:47:35.349  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
09-15 14:47:35.549  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
09-15 14:47:35.759  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
09-15 14:47:35.959  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1367)
09-15 14:47:36.509  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider﹕ Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {6557eeb8}
09-15 14:47:36.519  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
09-15 14:47:36.519  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(116)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
09-15 14:47:36.589  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/BrowserStartupController﹕ Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
09-15 14:47:36.599  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local SIRT entry from IRT, ignoring
09-15 14:47:36.629  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav E/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ BLUETOOTH permission is missing!
09-15 14:47:36.669  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
09-15 14:47:36.709  15698-15816/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav W/art﹕ Thread[15,tid=15816,Native,Thread*=0x497ad6d8,peer=0x655dd950,"Thread-220408"] attached without supplying a name
09-15 14:47:36.729  15698-15811/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav W/art﹕ Thread[16,tid=15811,Native,Thread*=0x4954e308,peer=0x655de948,"Thread-220409"] attached without supplying a name
09-15 14:47:36.819  15698-15816/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(890)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
09-15 14:47:36.859  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local SIRT entry from IRT, ignoring
09-15 14:47:37.059  15698-15826/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav W/art﹕ Thread[18,tid=15826,Native,Thread*=0x49677330,peer=0x6561da30,"Thread-220413"] attached without supplying a name
09-15 14:47:37.329  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav D/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ ==> onReceive: s=0, m=0, n=h2w, sb=true
09-15 14:47:37.329  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav D/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ reportUpdate: state=0, devices=[Speakerphone, Headset earpiece]
09-15 14:47:37.809  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-15 14:47:38.269  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-15 14:47:38.309  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
09-15 14:47:39.289  15698-15844/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav W/art﹕ Thread[21,tid=15844,Native,Thread*=0x4bcfe5e8,peer=0x65654700,"Thread-220416"] attached without supplying a name
09-15 14:47:39.309  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The 'options' directive has been replaced with 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' source expressions for the 'script-src' and 'style-src' directives. Please use those directives instead, as 'options' has no effect.", source: http://beta.html5test.com/ (0)
09-15 14:47:39.309  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The 'X-WebKit-CSP' headers are no longer supported. Please consider using the canonical 'Content-Security-Policy' header instead.", source:  (0)
09-15 14:47:39.779  15698-15812/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav W/art﹕ Thread[22,tid=15812,Native,Thread*=0x4f388538,peer=0x6565aca0,"Thread-220417"] attached without supplying a name
09-15 14:47:39.819  15698-15698/com.compinc.webviewwithnativenav I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'unsafe-inline' *". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
    ", source:  (0)
```

Comment: well what does the stacktrace say

Comment: @rds you can still output the stacktrace is what I am getting at

Comment: @tyzcj Yes true. Forget my comment.

Comment: i changed the contents of the catch to `throw new RuntimeException(e);` and now it skips right thru it to the post-execute function like everything is fine. any idea why that might be?

Comment: just do `e.printStacktrace()` in your catch block and watch the logcat for the output

Comment: @tyczj edited the stacktrace into the main post.

Comment: @Josh there is no error in what you posted so either you didnt copy the right stuff or there is no error being thrown

Comment: @tyczj yeah, i guess that's my confusion, why is it stopping in the catch block if there doesn't appear to be anything actually being caught. i figured it something with how `doInBackground` was working that i didn't quite understand.

Comment: instead of `return "xml error";` put `Log.i("Error!", "Error: " + e);` and it should tell you the error...

Comment: @SQLiteNoob it doesn't print anything, probably because there's no error just like with the stacktrace.

Comment: That is indeed bizarre. SOrry, I never use stacktrace because log is easier to find/read for me. My guess is that if there's a problem with parsing XML, it's probably going to be whitespace or an extra space, or missing a `/` - some kind of character error in the document.

Comment: @tyczj i think i've found the 'problem', so to speak. if a break point exists anywhere in the try-catch-catch function (anywhere, the return statements, the call to the other function, etc), it always returns the 'xml error' string. if no break points are there, it actually just continues on and functions properly. i actually had the breakpoint there to start, as i was debugging the sub fuction, and that's why i noticed it in this function. i think it may be a problem with the IDE (android studio), i'll report it and see if they say anything.

Comment: Good on you for figuring that out - I wouldn't expect the IDE to be the problem. I'm still on Eclipse until generous individuals like you get all the bugs worked out :D